# image icon in segmented bar in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

how to add the image icon in the segmented bar in nativescript-angular. can you please help me with this

```
 <SegmentedBar #tabs [selectedIndex]="selectSegment">
                <SegmentedBarItem title="test1"></SegmentedBarItem>
                <SegmentedBarItem title="test2"></SegmentedBarItem>
                <SegmentedBarItem title="test3"></SegmentedBarItem>
                <SegmentedBarItem title="test4"></SegmentedBarItem>
        </SegmentedBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SegmentedBar does not have options to assign images for each SegmentedBarItem. This is a valid scenario for TabView. For SegmentedBar you can only set background-image for the whole Segmented bar which can be used to apply image pattern but is no applicable to apply different icons for the different SegmentedBarItems

please have a look at the below link

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/790

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to add icons to your Nativescript Segmented Bar items is to use FontAwsome (or any other icon font for that matter).

1: Check out this (http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/videos/2016/03/07/nativescript-and-font-awesome.html) short five minute video on how to install FontAwsome to your {N} app.

2: Once you install the icon font. Assign `style="font-family: 'fontAwesome' "` attribute to `SegmentedBar` xml/"html" tag;

3: Check out http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/ to figure out the unicode for the icon you want to use and paste that unicode to the `title` attribute of the relevant `SegmentedBarItem` tag. **TIP:** make sure the code is in the right format. Don't copy the square braces shown on the cheatsheet, just what the string that appears inside them.

THATS IT! Your code should now look something like this:

```
<SegmentedBar #tabs [selectedIndex]="selectSegment" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome'; color: #eee; background-color: #31394C;">
            <SegmentedBarItem title="&#xf0c0;"></SegmentedBarItem>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="&#xf007;"></SegmentedBarItem>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="&#xf008;"></SegmentedBarItem>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="&#xf0f3;"></SegmentedBarItem>
</SegmentedBar>
```

This image:

[image]

shows the end result of the above code on an android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

For more flexible way you can create a custom SegmentedBar and adjust for your needs. Read more

[here](https://www.stanteq.com/blog/2/custom-segmented-bar-component-in-nativescript).